# How safe is it to rely on Sharepoint "ct100" identifiers?

Tags: sharepoint

There are various places in my Sharepoint generated web pages where element IDs are assigned values by Sharepoint with the prefix "ct100".

How safe is it to refer to these IDs in my javascript? 
How static are they? 
How likely are they to change for any reason?
Is there any documentation that discusses how they are generetad and answers the above questions?

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on research, the safest approach is to use css and jquery to identify and manipulate the "ct001" elements. I have tried this approach and it appears to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

"Safe" is relative here and depends on the *specific* page and controls involved.

The individual IDs that look like `ctXYZ` are generated automatically by the parent [ASP.Net Naming Container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) when the control has not been explicitly assigned an ID - that is, the ID is auto-generated like ct001, ct002, etc, making sure not to create duplicates.

The final Client ID - which is assigned as the id attribute in the HTML - is the made up of joining all the IDs of the control and all ancestors with underscores; thus the stability of a single Client ID is affected by multiple controls.

The generated Client IDs are generally guaranteed to remain stable only if the Control Tree is always re-created in the same way - this holds true in many cases, but it is not absolute. Dynamically adding or removing controls can easily break this assumption.

---

ASP.Net 4 (or 4.5?) introduced a different ID mode - primarily "Predictable", see the Naming Container link - but I do not believe that SharePoint uses this new feature anywhere; and it's definitely not used for IDs that contain `ctXYZ` components.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation - things I never knew.